# Filtering a Report Based on Subreport Criteria

Tags: ms-access, filter

I have a report with multiple subreports, with each of the subreports having Master/Child fields established.  The report works just as expected.

Usinb VBA, I would now to establish filters for the master based on information in the subreports' recordsets.

Is there any way to set the main report's "Filter" criteria to be based on one of its subreport's recordset?

For an example with just a master report/recordset and one subreport/recordset...

Master report/recordset = Properties
Subreport/recordset = Notices

There can be many "Notices" for each property so if I build one large query with the subforms' recordsets included with relationships (and set the criteria there), the master report generates a separate "page" for each of the valid entries on the subreport's recordset.

If I add the criteria to the subreport's recordset, the subreport will not be added to the main report (using the subreport's "On No Data" event, I set Cancel = True) but the main report still generates for the property.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried your 'one large query' as the main report RecordSource and applying filter? Exactly what is the issue? What is not working as you wish?

Comment: The "one large query" causes the main report to print multiple times since the relationships are one to many

Comment: I am not quite following description of data relationships and report design. Perhaps you just need to use report Sorting and Grouping features. Perhaps you just need to apply filter criteria. Maybe you need both. For a method to apply filter criteria, review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. If you want to provide db for analysis, upload to a fileshare site such as Box.com and post link.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up spending way too much time on this so I added "latest ..." fields to my parent table to capture the data I was trying to filter to and then created some code that would update those fields before the report is generated.